# Ocultar Opción en un Menu

Tags: html

Mi consulta es la siguiente, tengo un menú que se carga luego de loguearse, en el cual hay varias opciones una de ellas es Mantenedores del cual se despliega un submenu con otras opciones, lo que quiero realizar es ocultar una opción de ese submenu

Ejemplo

```
Mantenedores 
 Actas  
 Precios ---> Ocultar  
 Proyectos
```

y que se vea asi

```
Mantenedores  
Actas  
Proyectos
Desde ya muchas gracias.
```

Comment: ¿cual es tu código para partir de el?

Comment: ¿Deseas ocultar esa opción desde el lado del servidor al generar el HTML o del laso del cliente usando Javascript? En ambos casos necesitaremos el código HTML del menú y que nos digas qué lenguaje del lado del servidor usas y si usas frameworks como jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

supongo que tu menú esta creado con las etiquetas

o alguna parecida, para poder ocultar un elemento existen varios atributos Html, que permiten realizar esta función

ejemplo

Con alguna función javascripts o jquery puedes ocultar o mostrar según necesites

```
 $('#tuId).css('visibility', 'visible');

 $('#tuId').css('display', 'none');

$('#displayNone').click(function(e) {

  // Resetear, por si acaso has estado jugando con la otra propiedad
  $('#tuId').css('visibility', 'visible');

  if( $('#tuId').is(":visible") ) {
    $('#tuId').css('display', 'none'); 
  } else {
    $('#tuId).css('display', 'block');
  }
});

$('#visibilityHidden').click(function(e) {

  // Resetear, por si acaso has estado jugando con la otra propiedad
  $('#tuId').css('display', 'block');

  if( $('#tuId').css('visibility') != 'hidden' ) {
    $('#tuId').css('visibility', 'hidden');
  } else {
    $('#tuId').css('visibility', 'visible');
  }
});
```